# git push origin master result : REJECTED_OTHER_REASON

Tags: git

I've made a personal repository on my server.
I can clone it.
I've get errors on push

> refusing update ....
>
> ...
>
> 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
>
> ...
>
> ! [rmeote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
>
> error: failet to push some refs to 'ssh:// .....'

someone can help to figure this out?

thx a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have `master` checked out on the server, so you can't push `master` to the server.  There are three different ways to deal with this:

The Right Way is to start over with a `--bare` repository if you're going to work remotely.  Bare repositories don't have a "work tree"/working directory which means the repository will never have any branches checked out on the server itself. See [the Git FAQ](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Why_won.27t_I_see_changes_in_the_remote_repo_after_.22git_push.22.3F):

> *never* push into a repository that has a work tree attached to it, until you know what you are doing

The Easy Way to get it to work from where you are now is to simply create a fake branch and check it out on the server, so the working directory on the server is set to some branch other than `master` that you'll never try to push from the client.

The Hard Way requires that you create a trigger that resets your working directory on the server (you will lose any uncommitted changes on the server) (example [trigger shell script here](http://utsl.gen.nz/git/post-update)) and configure git to disable the error you got with `git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore`.  [This is used when you're using git for a webpage that you are editing remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152607/git-force-push-current-working-directory).  Again, see the FAQ above, if you only disable the error and don't setup the post-receive hook, your work tree will not be updated for you and you will have to `git reset --hard` on the server if you want to see the files you have pushed there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This answer solved mine problem too.